# How to include absolute video link in html5?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a website where a video is played at the background. So far, I used the video tag and used a link in source attribute. But, I'm not able to see the video in the background. Is it possible to just include a absolute link to the website without downloading the video?

```
    <video autoplay muted loop
source src="https://www.pexels.com/video/aerial-view-of-beautiful-resort-2169880/">
    </video>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to put your code into an runnable snippet that the community could run and diagnose?

Comment: the link you provided is a webpage that contains a video, not a direct link to a video file. You need a direct link to a video file. @Jojo

Answer (score 0):

### Disclaimer

This isn't reproducable if you don't have the correct expirence, This answer is meant for this question only! I'll add details at the end for people trying to reproduce it.

### Answer

This website uses an iframe to play the video, I was able to rip the iframe out and here is the code for playing the video:

```html
<iframe class="PhotoZoom_iframe__LeuQM" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/330412624?title=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;byline=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;muted=true" data-ruffle-polyfilled=""></iframe>
```

### Reproducable way

This involves using the devtools menu, if you don't know how to, this section won't invlove how to.

The goal is to get the video code out of inspect element and paste it in your code, first open up devtools and click "Elements", After that open dropdowns and see what's highlighted and check the code, repeat that until you've determined that the video is located in that code, After that right click the code and click "Copy > Copy Element", Then you have text in your clipboard to paste in your code to get the video.